# Create multi-dimensional array from another multi-dimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Lets say I have a multi-dimensional array like this :

```
$results = array(
    0 => array(
        'fruit' => 'apple',
        'colour' => 'green',
        'amount' => 50
    ),
    1 => array(
        'fruit' => 'orange',
        'colour' => 'orange',
        'amount' => 25
    ),
    2 => array(
        'fruit' => 'banana',
        'colour' => 'yellow',
        'amount' => 7
    )
);
```

And I want to create a new multi-dimensional array only using specific objects :

```
$newarray = array(
    0 => array(
        'fruit' => 'apple',
        'amount' => 50
    ),
    1 => array(
        'fruit' => 'orange',
        'amount' => 25
    ),
    2 => array(
        'fruit' => 'banana',
        'amount' => 7
    )
);
```

How would I do this? I've read a few different things and it seems like `array_map` or `array_column` might be the answer but I haven't found an example that fits my situation.

I've got as far as :

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if (!empty($result['fruit'])) {
      // create new array here but how do I specify the key => values?
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `->`? you need to use `[]` in arrays

Comment: The $results array is a json_decoded object. I just wrote it as a straight up php array to try and get across what I was trying to achieve. I've changed it so it's less confusing.

Comment: @MehdiBounya No what he does is perfectly fine. Well if he uses PHP 5.3 ... short array syntax is fully supported since PHP 5.6 ... but the => operator is still fine to assign values

Comment: I'm actually using 7.1 ;)

Comment: @sietse85 I'm not talking about `=>`, I'm talking about using `->` to access elements in arrays (check the edit history)

Comment: start using short syntax :) $array = [ 'a','b','c' ]; then ;)

Comment: haha yeah but I was trying to make the question as clear as possible. My actual array is nothing like this, I just wrote this so I can understand the concept of how I would achieve it.

Comment: To get back to the question, you can simply create an array with the data except `colour`

Comment: So just create each key and value element separately?

Comment: If the array is fixed and not big though

Comment: The actual $results array contains about 50 objects. I'm only using 3 of them so it shouldn't be too much of a drama.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in any case this is what you wan't correct?

```
foreach ($results as $key) {
    unset ($results[$key]['colour']);
}

print_r($results);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [fruit] => apple
        [amount] => 50
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [fruit] => orange
        [amount] => 25
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [fruit] => banana
        [amount] => 7
    )

)
```

Comment: Okay, great that's nice and simple. The only issue is that my actual $results array contains about 50 objects and I only want to use 3. It would be faster if I could specify which ones I wanted instead of unsetting 47 of them. How would I do that?

Comment: can you explain this a little bit more in depth? because i am not sure

Comment: @Mike I totally agree and apologies. But if I had posted an array with 50 objects it would have looked like a pigs ear.

Comment: @sietse The $results array is massive, it contains about 50 objects of which I only want to use 3 in the new array. Does that make sense?

Comment: Then see Mehdi's example

Comment: @spice I agree posting the whole thing would be unnecessary, but if you're not going to use your actual code, you should describe it as well as you can.

Comment: Yes he's nailed it for me but I'll give you the correct answer as you did in fact answer my original question correctly. I just wasn't clear enough about my particular use case. Thanks for your help bro.

Comment: @Mike Again, I totally agree. My bad. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This is suitable if the keys are fixed and you don't have too many of them:

```
$results = array(
    0 => array(
        'fruit' => 'apple',
        'colour' => 'green',
        'amount' => 50
    ),
    1 => array(
        'fruit' => 'orange',
        'colour' => 'orange',
        'amount' => 25
    ),
    2 => array(
        'fruit' => 'banana',
        'colour' => 'yellow',
        'amount' => 7
    )
);

$new = array();
foreach($results as $value){
    $new[] = array(
        'fruit' => $value['fruit'],
        'amount' => $value['amount']
    );
}
var_dump($new);
```

Gives:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'fruit' => string 'apple' (length=5)
      'amount' => int 50
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'fruit' => string 'orange' (length=6)
      'amount' => int 25
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'fruit' => string 'banana' (length=6)
      'amount' => int 7
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thanks bro! As mentioned below I will have to give the correct answer to @sietse85 as he answered my question correctly. I just wasn't clear enough about my particular use case which you have solved for me, so thanks again.

Comment: @spice No problem, [pick the answer that you find helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/387979)

Answer (score 0):

Set your keys on "$keys_to_search".
Is better than use unset.

```
$keys_to_search = ['fruit' => '','colour' => ''];

$results = array(
    0 => array(
        'fruit' => 'apple',
        'colour' => 'green',
        'amount' => 50
    ),
    1 => array(
        'fruit' => 'orange',
        'colour' => 'orange',
        'amount' => 25
    ),
    2 => array(
        'fruit' => 'banana',
        'colour' => 'yellow',
        'amount' => 7
    )
);




foreach($results as $key => $value){
    $result[] = array_intersect_key($value, $keys_to_search);  
}

print_r($result);
```